# Trouble when passing Javascript variables to JAVA with JXBrowser

Tags: javascript, java, html, jxbrowser

Using JxBrowser alongside JavaScript and HTML, I am running into issues implementing a form data input mechanism.

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013716-sending-form-data-to-java

The above documentation states how one would accomplish this, however on implementation I can not get the correct result.

My class is as follows:

```
String sourceString, targetString;
    int insertCost, deleteCost, subCost;

    final Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("User Input");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onFinishLoadingFrame(FinishLoadingEvent event) {
            if (event.isMainFrame()) {
                System.out.println("INNNN");
                final Browser browser = event.getBrowser();
                JSValue value = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
                System.out.println(value.toString());
                value.asObject().setProperty("Parameter", new Parameter());
            }
        }
    });      

    InputStream urlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../web/UserInputForm.html");
    String html = null;
    try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (urlStream))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String row;
        while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(row);
        }
        html = builder.toString(); 
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final String loadHTMLPath = html;

    Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>(){
        @Override
        public void invoke(Browser arg0) {
            browser.loadHTML(loadHTMLPath);
        }
    });

}

public static class Parameter {
    public void save(String sourceString, String targetString, int insertRadioValue, int deleteRadioValue, int subRadioValue, 
            int insertCostValue, int deleteCostValue, int subCostValue){
        System.out.println("INNNN");
        System.out.println("Source" + sourceString);
        System.out.println(targetString);
        System.out.println(insertRadioValue);
        System.out.println(deleteRadioValue);
        System.out.println(subRadioValue);
        System.out.println(insertCostValue);
        System.out.println(deleteCostValue);
        System.out.println(subCostValue);
    }
}
```

The JavaScript is in the head of my HTML file and looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sendFormData() {
        window.alert("HEKELEW");
        var sourceStringValue = myForm.elements['source'].value;
        window.alert(sourceStringValue);
        var targetStringValue = myForm.elements['target'].value;
        var insertRadioValue = myForm.elements['insertRadio'].value;
        var deleteRadioValue = myForm.elements['deleteRadio'].value;
        var subRadioValue = myForm.elements['subRadio'].value;
        var insertCostValue = myForm.elements['insert_cost'].value;
        var deleteCostValue = myForm.elements['delete_cost'].value;
        var subCostValue = myForm.elements['substitute_cost'].value;
        Paramater.save(sourceStringValue, targetStringValue, insertRadioValue, deleteRadioValue, subRadioValue, insertCostValue, deleteCostValue, subCostValue);
      }
</script>
```

I cannot access the variables in my Parameter class as I should be able to. I' sure the reason is very simplistic. Is it something to do with this line of code, I don't understand what needs to be passed through from the executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue command.

```
JSValue value = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue("window");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
 </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      Source String: <input name = "source" type="text"> <br>

      Target String: <input name="target" type="text" ><br>

       Insertion <input type="radio" name="insertion_radio" name =      "insertRadio"><br>

       Deletion <input type="radio" name="deletion_radio" name =      "deleteRadio"><br>

       Substitute <input type="radio" name="substitution_radio" name =      "subRadio"><br>

      Insert Cost <input type="number" name="insert_cost"><br>

       Delete Cost <input type="number" name="delete_cost"><br>

       Substitute Cost <input type="number" name="substitute_cost"><br>
     <div>
     <input type="button" value="enter" onclick="sendFormData();"/><br>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the complete sample HTML that can be used with the Java and JavaScript code you have provided? In addition, it is not clear when the `sendFormData` JavaScript function is called.

Comment: @AnnaDolbina All edited to include HTML in full. The JS script is exactly as is above just in my HTML header . Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working sample with all the modifications.

Java:

```
public class BrowserSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("User Input");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.addScriptContextListener(new ScriptContextAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onScriptContextCreated(ScriptContextEvent event) {
                JSValue value = browser.executeJavaScriptAndReturnValue(event.getJSContext().getFrameId(),"window");
                value.asObject().setProperty("Parameter", new Parameter());
            }
        });

       browser.addConsoleListener(new ConsoleListener() {
           @Override
           public void onMessage(ConsoleEvent event) {
               System.out.println("event.getMessage() = " + event.getMessage());
           }
       });

        InputStream urlStream = BrowserSample.class.getResourceAsStream("web/UserInputForm.html");
        String html;
        try (BufferedReader urlReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlStream))) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String row;
            while ((row = urlReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(row);
            }
            html = builder.toString();
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        final String loadHTMLPath = html;

        Browser.invokeAndWaitFinishLoadingMainFrame(browser, new Callback<Browser>(){
            @Override
            public void invoke(Browser arg0) {
                browser.loadHTML(loadHTMLPath);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Parameter {
        public void save(String sourceString, String targetString, String insertRadioValue, String deleteRadioValue, String subRadioValue,
                String insertCostValue, String deleteCostValue, String subCostValue){
            System.out.println("INNNN");
            System.out.println("Source" + sourceString);
            System.out.println(targetString);
            System.out.println(insertRadioValue);
            System.out.println(deleteRadioValue);
            System.out.println(subRadioValue);
            System.out.println(insertCostValue);
            System.out.println(deleteCostValue);
            System.out.println(subCostValue);
        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function sendFormData() {
        window.alert("HEKELEW");
        var sourceStringValue = myForm.elements['source'].value;
        window.alert(sourceStringValue);
        var targetStringValue = myForm.elements['target'].value;
        var insertRadioValue = myForm.elements['insertRadio'].value;
        var deleteRadioValue = myForm.elements['deleteRadio'].value;
        var subRadioValue = myForm.elements['subRadio'].value;
        var insertCostValue = myForm.elements['insert_cost'].value;
        var deleteCostValue = myForm.elements['delete_cost'].value;
        var subCostValue = myForm.elements['substitute_cost'].value;
        Parameter.save(sourceStringValue, targetStringValue, insertRadioValue, deleteRadioValue, subRadioValue, insertCostValue, deleteCostValue, subCostValue);
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
      Source String: <input name = "source" type="text"> <br>

      Target String: <input name="target" type="text" ><br>

       Insertion <input type="radio" name = "insertRadio"><br>

       Deletion <input type="radio"  name = "deleteRadio"><br>

       Substitute <input type="radio"  name = "subRadio"><br>

      Insert Cost <input type="number" name="insert_cost"><br>

       Delete Cost <input type="number" name="delete_cost"><br>

       Substitute Cost <input type="number" name="substitute_cost"><br>
     <div>
     <input type="button" value="enter" onclick="sendFormData();"/><br>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: quick question, as I have a HTML doc for my UserInput I also have one for the main page of my app and one to say hello. How do I reload HTML onto the same browser instance so that I don't have to create a new browser frame for each html doc I have?

Comment: Each subsequent `Browser.loadHTML()` call will load the specified HTML string in the `Browser` instance. Therefore, you can call `loadHTML()` once more to load another HTML in the same `Browser` instance.

Comment: Thanks, Anna, may have a few more questions for you in the near future!